# How to parse Flickr using flickrapi in Python

Tags: python, flickr

I'm trying to create a simple app that lists recent photos posted to Flickr based on geography.

I've created the query using flickerapi, but struggling with the API notes as to how to actually return the results so I can actually parse the attributes I actually want.

This is my query:

```
import flickrapi
api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, format="etree")

flickr.photos_search(api_key = api_key, tags = "stoke", privacy_filter = 1, safe_search=1, lon="-2.1974224", lat="53.0232691", radius=32, sort= "date-posted-des")
```

It returns an object:

```
<Element 'rsp' at 0x1077a6b10>
```

All I want to do is examine what attributes are available so I can extract the bits I want - but I can't see a method which will return this. What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case what you might want is:

> ```
>  "flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key) 
>   photos = flickr.photos_search(user_id='73509078@N00', per_page='10') 
>   sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')"
> ```
>
> - [flickrapi docs](http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/apidoc/)

So what it does is gets the returned `XML doc` and gives to you as an `ElementTree` object so it's easier to handle. (this is the `sets` object). the photos object cannot do that unfortunately.

[ElementTree docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

so to get a general list of attributes first use the `.tag` and `.attrib` methods of the root node of the tree that is passed to you.

You can use sets as the `root` in the examples in the ElementTree docs :)

an example use it gives is:

> ```
> sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='73509078@N00')
>
> sets.attrib['stat'] => 'ok'
> sets.find('photosets').attrib['cancreate'] => '1'
>
> set0 = sets.find('photosets').findall('photoset')[0]
>
> +-------------------------------+-----------+
> | variable                      | value     |
> +-------------------------------+-----------+
> | set0.attrib['id']             | u'5'      |
> | set0.attrib['primary']        | u'2483'   |
> | set0.attrib['secret']         | u'abcdef' |
> | set0.attrib['server']         | u'8'      |
> | set0.attrib['photos']         | u'4'      |
> | set0.title[0].text            | u'Test'   |
> | set0.description[0].text      | u'foo'    |
> | set0.find('title').text       | 'Test'    |
> | set0.find('description').text | 'foo'     |
> +-------------------------------+-----------+
>
> ... and similar for set1 ...
> ```
>
> [-flickrapi docs](http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/documentation/#response-parser-elementtree)

---

Another question you may have been indirectly asking:

In general given a python `class` you can do:

```
cls.__dict__
```

to get *some* of the attributes available to it.

Given a general python object you can use `vars(obj)` or `dir(obj)`

e.g.:

```
class meh():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cat = 'dinosaur'
        self.number = 1
    # some example methods - don't actually do this
    # this is not a good use of a method
    # or object-oriented programming in general

    def add_number(self, i):
        self.number+=i

j = meh()
print j.__dict__
{'number': 1, 'cat': 'dinosaur'}
```

this returns the namespace's dict that is used for the object:

> "Except for one thing. Module objects have a secret read-only
>   attribute called **dict** which returns the dictionary used to
>   implement the module’s namespace; the name **dict** is an attribute
>   but not a global name. Obviously, using this violates the abstraction
>   of namespace implementation, and should be restricted to things like
>   post-mortem debuggers." - [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

`dir` returns

> "Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local
>   scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes
>   for that object." [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

and

`vars` just returns the **dict** attribute:

> "return the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any
>   other object with a **dict** attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable **dict**
>   attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
>   **dict** attributes (for example, new-style classes use a dictproxy to prevent direct dictionary updates)." [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)

it should be noted that *nothing* can give you *everything* available to an object at run time due to crafty things you can do to modify an object.

Comment: Worth noting that __dict__ won't actually work in OP's situation since there's no direct import of the returned object.

Comment: it gives attributes of the namespace that was used for the object @SlaterTyranus

Comment: Thank you for adding the clarification, the answer was quite misleading before that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what a given object has I would advise one of the following:

```
vars(item)  # To see all the variable associated with it
```

or

```
dir(item)  # To see all of the methods associated with it
```

To be more precise `dir()` returns all of the variables in scope, but for your object, and given that functions are objects in python the result is the same.

There's also:

```
globals()  # To see everything in global scope
```

and

```
locals()  # To see everything in local scope.
```

Though in your specific case I would just refer to the docs for the Element object that is directly returned, though I've found `vars()` and `dir()` to be invaluable in everyday coding.

Docs are here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html